# What path should I give for cmake when installing IMPACT?

Tags: software-installation, cmake

I am trying to install software called 'IMPACT' on my Ubuntu OS. I'm trying to follow these steps to complete installation:

> #### Requirements:
>
> CMake v 2.8 or higher.
>
> #### === UNIX / Linux / Mac OS X ===
>
> 1. Create a build directory (e.g. `build`) that
>      is separate from the source directory. Enter said directory.
> 2. Issue `cmake <options> path-to-impact-sources`
>
>    Some useful options, some of which are standard `cmake` options, are:
>
>    - `DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=path-to-install-destination` - Sets the install directory
>    - `DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=c-compiler-of-choice`
>    - `DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=c++-compiler-of-choice`
>        Dictate what compilers to use.
>    - `DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug|Release` - Release builds are the default and will produce a performance optimised installation. Debug builds are, obviously, for debugging and will produce debugging symbols.
>    - `DIMPACT_STOPWATCH=1` - Activates the timing functions in IMPACT. Partial wall times will be reported. Total wall time will be slightly increased.
>    - `DIMPACT_NO_OPENMP=1` - Turns off OpenMP support. That means no parallelism.
> 3. Issue `make`
> 4. Issue `make install`

So what I did, I downloaded the IMPACT tarball and untarred it in a directory called `Documents`. Then I created a build directory in the IMPACT folder. Then I issued the first command with first option giving path to `cmake: /usr/local/bin`. The error was that it failed to locate the `Cmake.txt` file.

I am new to Ubuntu, please tell me a simple way to install it in layman's language. For example: what path I should give for Cmake? do I need to use all options one by one? Is the path for Cmake always /`usr/local/bin`? and simplify the steps of installation.

Comment: Instead of vague statements like *"Then I issued the first command with first option giving path to cmake: /usr/local/bin"* please [edit] your question to show us the actual command you ran, and the exact error.

Answer (score 1):

To find out where `cmake` is installed you can run `which cmake`. If that doesn't return anything, you can install it with `sudo apt install cmake`. You shouldn't have to put in the full path. You should just be able to run `cmake path-to-impact-sources`. Once `cmake` has been installed, you should be able to install `IMPACT`.